# "Письмо (к) кому-то": когда можно употреблять предлог "к"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, предлоги

газета.ru — не дворовая стенгазета. Почему же "письмо **к** генеральному директору"? Неужели допустимо так говорить?

*Максим Галкин высмеял открытое письмо своего коллеги Андрея Малахова **к** генеральному директору Первого канала Константину Эрнсту*. ([газета.ru](https://www.gazeta.ru/culture/news/2017/08/21/n_10461788.shtml?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=lentainform&utm_campaign=gazeta.ru&utm_term=1271723s1304&utm_content=5613287))

Дополнение.

К своему удивлению, обнаружил в Нацкорпусе немало примеров, начиная от "Письма к матери" Есенина и включая Брюсова ("Потом сел писать письмо к Анне"). Поэтому
меняю вопрос с "можно ли?" на "когда можно?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"**Письмо** [обращённое] **к** кому-то" (письмо как форма обращения) - вполне допустимое выражение. Примеры: стихотворение Есенина "Письмо к женщине", "Письмо к съезду" Ленина. Нельзя только "написать" или "адресовать" письмо "**к**" кому-то. В сочетании же с существительным предлог направления (к, от) частично выполняет функцию отсутствующего глагола, добавляя ясности. В некоторых случаях без предлога невозможно по падежному окончанию отличить автора письма от адресата (письмо матери = письмо от/к матери). Это о том, когда "нужно". "Желательно" это бывает в случаях, когда акцентируется содержание письма (ссылка на него, последующее цитирование и т. п.); если же просто упоминается факт написания или отправки письма, то употребление предлога может выглядеть излишним (это зависит от контекста).

**P.S.** Сходная функция предлога (замещение опущенного слова) наблюдается по тому же смысловому поводу и в английском языке: to write **to** somebody (написать кому-то; опущено слово "письмо", и требуется предлог - иначе адресат оказывается в "винительном падеже") -> to write somebody a letter (предлог направления при таком порядке слов не употребляется).

Answer (score 3):

См. [***Розенталь Д.Э. "Пунктуация и управление в русском языке":***](http://upravlenie.academic.ru/1642)

> **ПИСЬМО**
>
> ***кому*** и ***к кому***; ***кого*** и ***от кого***.
>
> 1. *Письмо отцу. Письмо Белинского В. П. Боткину.*
> 2. ***Письмо к матери*** (во избежание двузначности сочетания «письмо матери»:
>
> а) письмо, написанное матерью;
>
> б) письмо, адресованное матери).
>
> 3. *Письмо отца*.
> 4. *Письмо от матери*
>
> (во избежание двузначности при совпадении форм род. и дат. падежей).

Comment: Ваша ссылка ведет не к Розенталю, а к Словарю управления.

Comment: _М_Г: Ваша ссылка ведет не к Розенталю, а к Словарю управления._ === ??? А кем он написан, этот словарь, как не Розенталем? См. по ссылке: **"_Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д.Э. Розенталь_."**